# Spark 2.4.3 - What to do when database table schema has number type?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to load data from a database table (Teradata) with spark, but the schema of the table has the type NUMBER without precision and scale. As we can see here https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/8780.

So when I load a table with columns of the the "NUMBER" that have Float values in theses columns, in the spark dataframe the precision of theses values appear as NUMBER(38,0) and the precision of theses values are lost.

Example:

Teradata:

```
values
50.00
94.30
23.30
20.01
```

Dataframe spark:

```
values
50
94
23
20
```

Someone can help me with it ?

Comment: you can specify the schema of the table while loading.

Comment: spark doc:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html , refer 'customSchema' -  property name. This helps to override the default datatype in spark jdbc read.